# How do you set a variable as the label for an input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my sample input field:

```
<div class="md-form form-sm">
    <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control">
    <label for="form1" class="">Example label</label>
</div>
```

If i want to set the label as a variable so i can update it. How would I do that? Please bear in mind, I'm new to JS and Jquery and those are the only tools i'm currently using. I'm not using any other frameworks and would prefer not to at this point, unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: use a framework for dynamic html.

Comment: can you elaborate your question ???

Comment: What variable? Where is it coming from?

Comment: I have a quantity variable that i will be using such as `cart.blueQty` it gets calculated by other functions. I'ld like to be able to display that in the label of the input field. My end goal is to be able to have the user tap the field and type in a new number if they wanted to edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank everyone for their answers. Like i said, I'm new to JS and I appreciate all the help. I ended up doing this:

for the input I used:

```
<div class="md-form form-sm">
    <input type="text" id="blueCartQty" maxlength="2" class="form-
        control">
    <label for="blueCartQty" id="blueInputLabel" class=""></label>
</div>
```

And to put my variable as the label I put this in my JS file:

```
$("#blueInputLabel").html(cart.blueQty);
```

cart.blueQty gets updated in a function and i wanted it to always show the current value.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a dynamic templating framework of somesort. I've used Underscore.js , it has templating functionality that gets the job done:

http://underscorejs.org/#template

Answer (score 0):

```
> from: <label for="form1" class="">Example label</label>
> ˀ
> to: 
<label for="form1" class=""><div id="mylabel">Example
 label</div></label>

<script>
     content = "this is my variable text";
     document.getElementById("mylabel").innerHTML = content; 
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you add an inner div element rather than just settting the label's `.innerHTML` directly?

Comment: depends on the style of coding.  I update divs because its easier for responsive to update div elements.  It doesn't make it wrong, its just a preference or taste after a few years of coding.  It may not be necessary but it does easy to remember when you develop a style.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using pure JS / jQuery.

Firstly, create a variable that links to the DOM element (assuming you gave it a class of `label`):

```
var test = $(".label")[0];
```

Then, you can simply change the value of its `innerHTML` field to change the text inside:

```
test.innerHTML = "test";
```

Thus, your full code would be like:

```js
var test;

window.onload = function() {
  test = $(".label")[0];
  
  //At any other point in your code when you would want to change it
  test.innerHTML = "Another label";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="md-form form-sm">
    <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control">
    <label for="form1" class="label">Example label</label>
</div>
```

I don't believe that there is a way to this better (i.e. by just setting a single variable rather than a property) other than using another framework - such as [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) as mentioned by others.

Comment: Why would you mix jQuery with `.innerHTML`? If you're using jQuery in the first place just `$("label").html(...)` is neater.

Comment: OP wanted a variable to change, not a function, and he has tagged as jQuery, so it would make no sense to use `document.getElementById()`. But I agree, the best way to do this is to use the `html()` function. Not sure why OP needs a variable.

Comment: I don't think the OP really understands what they're asking for, but if you want a variable that references the element: `var test = $("label");`, then later, `test.html("new text")`.

Comment: That works depending on your interpretation of the question. He implied that he wanted to *"set the label as a variable so i can update it"*, and that has numerous advantages (off the top of my head, being able to use `+=` to append to the `innerHTML` rather than having to get the value, etc, etc). He wants to use it like a variable, rather than like a function.